# Calculating time difference by groups

Tags: mysql, sql, r, analytics

I have a question about calculating the time difference for different sources and targets.

```
Table1:         

Source      Target     Time                   TimeDif(wrong) (right)
1.2.3.4     2.3.4.5    2012-01-03 21:50:40    3               3
1.2.3.4     2.3.4.5    2014-01-03 21:50:43    5               5
1.2.3.4     2.3.4.5    2014-01-03 21:50:48    3               NULL
2.2.2.2     4.4.4.4    2014-01-03 21:50:51    3               4
2.2.2.2     4.4.4.4    2014-01-03 21:50:55    4               4
2.2.2.2     4.4.4.4    2014-01-03 21:50:59    4               NULL
....        ....       ......
```

Right now I calculate the time difference with:

```
diffTime <- difftime(time[1:(length(time)-1)] , time[2:length(time)]) * -1
```

The problem is that the time difference by calculating this method are not correct. That means the method calculate the whole column and does not make any decision between different sources and targets. I'm not sure if this problem can be fixed by the package (sqldf) to query and to group the data together. The query should also implement the method, but I think that is not possible. So would be nice if you have any solutions.

Comment: Can you first tell us what you are trying to compute here?

Comment: Here's the problem: Assuming you are trying to compute the lead for each target/source group, MySQL does not support analytic functions.  So you might do better with a different approach.

Comment: I try to compute the time difference of the access from source to target. So it is not possible with MySQL :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing you want to do stuff in R, you need a grouping function. With for example `group_by` from `dplyr` you can do that:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(Source, Target) %>% 
  mutate(tdif = lead(Time) - Time)
```

the result:

```
   Source  Target                Time          tdif
   <fctr>  <fctr>              <dttm>        <time>
1 1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5 2012-01-03 21:50:40 63158403 secs
2 1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5 2014-01-03 21:50:43        5 secs
3 1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5 2014-01-03 21:50:48       NA secs
4 2.2.2.2 4.4.4.4 2014-01-03 21:50:51        4 secs
5 2.2.2.2 4.4.4.4 2014-01-03 21:50:55        4 secs
6 2.2.2.2 4.4.4.4 2014-01-03 21:50:59       NA secs
```

Note that the first `tdiff` value is much larger than what you stated in the intended output. This is richt and due to the fact that the date of the first timestamp is from 2012, while the other timestamps are from 2014.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i tried it on my dataset and it works 100%. Thank you very much! I have to learn more about the package (dplyr)! :)